# List of drop-down buttons. Onmousover show button description on right side

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, mouseevent

I have a list of buttons and buttons with drop-down menu.
When I place my mouse over each button, it shows a brief description of the button at the bottom of the list (see example).

**Now**  it is working only for first level buttons but not for drop-down list items.

**In summary**, I would like to:

1. Show description (`onmouseover`) of each item on the RIGHT from the list, as shown in the image (not at the bottom, like it is now)
2. Show description (`onmouseover`) not just for first level buttons but also for items in the drop-down lists.

I would be very thankful for a working solution.

[image: Please click to see the image for layout]

```css
.element-1,
.element-2,
.element-3 {
  display: none;
}

.a-1:hover~.element-1 {
  display: block;
}

.a-2:hover~.element-2 {
  display: block;
}

.a-3:hover~.element-3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <font color="#909497">Drop-down Buttons list</font>
</p>
<div class="container" style="width: 350px; height: 22px;">
  <button title="Description 1" class="a-1" id="menu1" onclick="window.open(&#39;http://link.com&#39;, &#39;_blank&#39;)" type="button" style="width: 268px; height: 68px;">Button 1</button>
  <div align="left" class="dropdown" style="width: 333px; height: 34px;">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="menu1" aria-expanded="false" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width: 268px; height: 34px;">Drop-Down Button 1 
         <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul title="Drop-down item 1 description" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li class="a-2" role="presentation">
        <a tabindex="-1" class="a-2" href="https://link2.com/" target="_blank">Drop-down item 1</a></li>
      <li title="Drop-down item 2 description" role="presentation">
        <a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" href="https://link3.com" target="_blank">Drop-down item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="menu1" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width: 268px; height: 34px;">Drop-Down Button 3 
         <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li title="drop-down item 3 description" class="a-2" role="presentation">
        <a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" href="http://link6.com" target="_blank">Drop-down item 3 </a></li>
      <li title="drop-down item 4 description" role="presentation">
        <a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" href="#">Drop-down item 4 </a></li>
      <li title="drop-down item 5 description" role="presentation">
        <a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" href="#">Drop-down item 5 </a></li>
      <li title="drop-down item 6 description" role="presentation">
        <a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" href="http://link.com" target="_blank">Drop-down item 6</a></li>
      <li title="Drop-down item 7 description" role="presentation">
        <a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" href="#">Drop-down item 7</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button title="Button 4 description" class="a-2" id="menu1" onclick="window.open(&#39;http://link.com&#39;, &#39;_blank&#39;)" type="button" style="width: 268px; height: 34px;">Button 4</button><button title="Button 4 description" class="a-3" id="menu1"
    onclick="window.open(&#39;http://link.com&#39;, &#39;_blank&#39;)" type="button" style="width: 268px; height: 34px;">Button 5 </button>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
  <div class="element-1" style="width: 350px;">
    <img width="45" height="45" src="https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX2310920.jpg" data-themekey="#" alt="" />
    <br/>Button 1 description</div>
  <div class="element-2" style="width: 350px;">Button 4 description</div>
  <div class="element-3" style="width: 350px;">Button 5 description</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use the "title" attribute to show a description on your dropdown buttons?

Comment: I don't use title because it shows just small "alt" text and there is no possibility to add images (like for button 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've moved the description elements right after their buttons.
Then, I've added the class `description` to easily target all the description `div`s,
and another one, `descripted`, to easily target all the buttons with description…

Add some CSS and here you go:

```css
.container {
  /* Added for visibility */
  background: #eee;
}

.description {
  display: none;
  /* The absolute positioning refers to the container. */
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(100%, -100%);
}

.descripted:hover+.description {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <font color="#909497">Drop-down Buttons list</font>
</p>
<div class="container" style="width: 350px; height: 22px;">
  <button title="Description 1" class="a-1 descripted" id="menu1" onclick="window.open(&#39;http://link.com&#39;, &#39;_blank&#39;)" type="button" style="width: 268px; height: 68px;">Button 1</button>
  <div class="description" style="width: 350px;">
    <img width="45" height="45" src="https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX2310920.jpg" data-themekey="#" alt="" />
    <br/>Button 1 description
  </div>
  <div align="left" class="dropdown" style="width: 333px; height: 34px;">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle descripted" id="menu1" aria-expanded="false" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width: 268px; height: 34px;">Drop-Down Button 1<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <div class="description" style="width: 350px;">
      <img width="45" height="45" src="https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX2310920.jpg" data-themekey="#" alt="" />
      <br/>Drop-Down 1 description
    </div>

    <ul title="Drop-down item 1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li class="a-2 descripted" role="presentation">
        <a tabindex="-1" class="a-2" href="https://link2.com/" target="_blank">Drop-down item 1</a>
      </li>
      <div class="description" style="width: 350px;">
        <img width="45" height="45" src="https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX2310920.jpg" data-themekey="#" alt="" />
        <br/>Drop-Down item 1 description
      </div>
      <li class="descripted" title="Drop-down item 2" role="presentation">
        <a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" href="https://link3.com" target="_blank">Drop-down item 2</a>
      </li>
      <div class="description" style="width: 350px;">
        <img width="45" height="45" src="https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX2310920.jpg" data-themekey="#" alt="" />
        <br/>Drop-Down item 2 description
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="menu1" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width: 268px; height: 34px;">Drop-Down Button 3<span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li title="drop-down item 3 description" class="a-2" role="presentation">
        <a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" href="http://link6.com" target="_blank">Drop-down item 3 </a>
      </li>
      <li title="drop-down item 4 description" role="presentation">
        <a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" href="#">Drop-down item 4 </a>
      </li>
      <li title="drop-down item 5 description" role="presentation">
        <a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" href="#">Drop-down item 5 </a>
      </li>
      <li title="drop-down item 6 description" role="presentation">
        <a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" href="http://link.com" target="_blank">Drop-down item 6</a>
      </li>
      <li title="Drop-down item 7 description" role="presentation">
        <a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" href="#">Drop-down item 7</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button title="Button 4 description" class="a-2" id="menu1" onclick="window.open(&#39;http://link.com&#39;, &#39;_blank&#39;)" type="button" style="width: 268px; height: 34px;">Button 4</button><button title="Button 4 description" class="a-3" id="menu1"
    onclick="window.open(&#39;http://link.com&#39;, &#39;_blank&#39;)" type="button" style="width: 268px; height: 34px;">Button 5 </button>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
</div>
```

I've done it only on the 2 first buttons, but you get the idea!
Feel free to comment if you want some modification.

Hope it helps!